# Cреднее время вычисления всех процессов очереди

Tags: информатика

> В памяти однопроцессорной системы запущены четыре процесса р1, р2, р3 и р4. Они образуют циклическую очередь без приоритетов. Перед запуском вычислительной системы первым в очереди стоял р1, вторым – р2, третьим – p3 и четвертым – p4. Известно количество условных временных тактов процессора, необходимых для вычисления каждого из этих процессов полностью в случае непрерывного вычисления: для р1 – 18, для р2 – 24, для р3 – 48, для р4 – 42, а также известен квант времени (К = 6), представляющий собой количество тактов процессора, выделяемых для непрерывного вычисления очередного процесса. После прохождения очередного кванта времени, вычислявшийся процесс помещается в конец очереди, а из начала очереди для вычисления берется следующий процесс. Если в очереди остался незавершенным только один единственный процесс, то все процессорное время выделяется ему.
>
> Время исполнения одного процесса равно количеству тактов процессора, прошедших с момента начала вычисления этого процесса (первого попадания этого процесса на вычисление в процессор) до окончания вычисления процесса.
>
> Определите среднее время вычисления всех процессов очереди, разделив сумму времени исполнения всех процессов на количество процессов, которое было в очереди перед запуском вычислительной системы. В ответе укажите число с точностью до второго знака после запятой.
>
> Примечание: при решении задачи временем на выполнение операционной системой операций по планированию и смене вычисляемого процесса следует пренебречь.

Comment: @Евгений536, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
такты->     6      12     18     24     30     36     42     48     54     60
      ------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
p1    [work]                      [work]                      [work](завершился)
p2           [work]                      [work]                      [work]
p3                  [work]                      [work]                      [work]
p4                         [work]                      [work]               и т.д.
```

примерно так

Comment: и не догадался, что когда процесс помещается в очередь, он ведь до сих пор работает!